# Looking for an esoteric graph theory algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

So I'm sure this is an unusual question for this type of site, but I am to give a talk on algorithms for discrete graphs in a few weeks. It has been specified that the talk is to be on some algorithm which will be unfamiliar for those attending. It it to be some graph traversal algorithm at about the junior level. Does anyone know of any such algorithm which is a bit removed from main stream graph theory?

Comment: What are the students supposed to learn from this algorithm? For example, you could do a random walk of the graph. Does this help in their understanding? BFS and DFS are common. There's also search algorithms that could do a traversal.

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a 
[general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). 
Please note also [this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20) and
[this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; 
you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems 
explained there.